# Is asking someone to resign a personal attack?

Tags: resignation

What is a personal attack? Is it a "personal attack" to ask someone in management to resign? Is there a way to word it differently so it isn't a personal attack?

Comment: are you asking someone to resign from their job, and was accused of having a personal agenda against them? do you have a personal agenda against this employee

Comment: Please clarify your question.  As an employee, you don't get to request a member of management to resign...

Comment: It depends on the situation and what exactly you mean by ask. It's possible to imagine some situations where it is not an attack, e.g. Boss: "To be honest, I really don't want to work here any more." You: "Have you considered resigning?".

Comment: If you mean do I have the authority to follow up the request with an order of termination, no I do not have the authority.

Comment: Asking someone above you in the corporate hierarchy to resign is equivalent to asking to be fired - personal attack or not.

Comment: Have you discussed it with your team? If you alone made this decision to ask your manager to step down, then you better have some extremely good reasons.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an attack, i.e. "Layoffs are coming, the company is out of money, we should resign"... but short of that it probably is.

Comment: I once told a manager I could learn his job in 5 minutes and do it better than him, but he was way too stupid to ever learn to do mine.... it's all in the delivery

Comment: @kush  If someone below you at your workplace asked you to resign, tomorow morning, would you take it as a personal attack?  Would you be insulted?  Would you want to know their reasoning?

Answer (score 4):

What various comments and Joe's answer have alluded to is that when you're asking someone to resign your position relative to them matters hugely.

If you don't have any form of seniority or authority over the person you're asking to resign not only can it easily come across as a personal attack it's also extremely unlikely to actually achieve anything.

There are occasions where calls can be made for a public figure to resign (such as politicians) but it's unlikely to get anywhere without a significant number of people asking for the same thing.

If you were a user on a website asking a member of staff at the site's operating company to resign (just pulling an [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology#comment1096959_334248) out of the air) then it's going to look pretty personal (and be pretty ineffectual) - it's not unheard of for a company to fire someone if they feel that having the person remain affects them too badly (whether it's correct or not it does happen) -  but asking someone to resign, essentially asking them to fall on their proverbial sword. It doesn't really matter how politely you phrase this - it's going to be taken as a personal attack, because that's what it is - you're essentially paraphrasing:

> I want you to lose your job

And, well.. people tend to take that pretty personally.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your goal.  In general, if you ask someone to resign, what you are saying is that they are incompetent and don't deserve to have their position because they are incompetent.  Saying someone is incompetent is definitely a personal attack.  So if the message behind your meaning is "you are incompetent, you should quit and be replaced with someone who can do your job better", then yes, that is a personal attack.  If that is your meaning, there's really no way to say it so that it's not a personal attack, because it is intended that way.

If you mean something else, then you'll need to clarify your question because that's the only answer I can think of.

Comment: No, I definitely don't think they're incompetent or malicious.

Answer (score 2):

> What is a personal attack?

https://www.yourdictionary.com/personal-attack

"Making of an abusive remark on or relating to one's person instead of providing evidence when examining another person's claims or comments."

> Is it a "personal attack" to ask someone in management to resign?

That depends on several factors:

- Your authority (or lack thereof) in asking for a resignation
- The basis you state for asking for a resignation
- The words you use when you ask

> Is there a way to word it differently so it isn't a personal attack?

Certainly.

Make your asking about facts, not feelings or innuendo. Choose your words carefully. Make sure you have the authority to ask for the resignation.

Make the resignation about a solution to an actual problem, not just about the individual being asked.

Comment: > Make sure you have the authority to ask for the resignation.

How?

Comment: So only the people who have the authority to fire can ask for a resignation? So a request for resignation is actually a threat to fire?

Comment: @kush - Do you really think there is a workplace were it is acceptable for an employee to ask their manager to resign?  Of course, nothing prevents you from saying that to your manager, but in all likelihood, this isn't going to work out too well for you.

Comment: @kush - You really shouldn't ever threaten to fire somebody.  Threating to fire somebody, is a great way to be taken to court, over a violation of a worker's rights.  *Based on the questions you are asking, it sounds like you shouldn't ask anyone to resign, since you are not in a postion to fire them.*  If somebody other than my supervisor asked me to resign, I would tell them to "pound sand" and walk away, then have a polite conversation with my supervisor about that person.